# Why does IPsec use tunnel-mode for an external laptop? Could transport-mode be used? Why can't a gateway control access in transport-mode?

Tags: authentication, access-control, ipsec, tunneling

In an IPsec Secure gateway setup, why is tunnel-mode used when an external laptop wants to access an internal service protected by a firewall? Is tunnel-mode necessary or could transport-mode be used instead? **Why** can't a gateway perform access-control if it was transport-mode communication?

[image]

Comment: Transport mode retains the original header. This reveals information about the traffic, and can't easily cross NAT. Thus it's simply easier to use tunnel mode with RFC1918 addressing.

Comment: @vidarlo thanks for answer. but what kind of authentication/access-control is performed?

Comment: Have you read up on IPSsec on Wikipedia?

Comment: @vidarlo please, just tell me the name of the authentication/access-control and I look up for it. I just don't know what is the access-control performed by the gateway/firewall. is that provided just by AH/ESP? is that provided by digital signature, public key, revised public key, pre-shared key? is that provided by other stuff checked by the gateway/firewall?

Comment: my professor said: "since we have authentication, gateway also performs access-control: have you the right to create a tunnel with this network? and he got a list of authorized people"

I don't know what is referring to

Comment: Please read the wikipedia page on ipsec or your textbook. Both probably explains the protocol fairly well. If there's unclear details, feel free to ask, but don't ask us to explain the entire protocol for you.

Comment: @vidarlo I'm not asking to you to explain me the protocol, I just don't know what mechanism we are referring to when we talk about that kind of access-control. Since there can be multiple interpretations of my professor words

Comment: Then ask your professor for a clarification?